# Why appending a list is faster than changing the value of a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, performance

To my surprise this code:

```
N = 10**8

l = []
L = np.zeros(N)

t1 = time()
for i in range(N):
    l.append(1)
t2 = time()

print("Adding into list took:", t2 - t1, "s")

t1 = time()
for i in range(N):
    L[i] = 1
t2 = time()

print("Adding into array took:", t2 - t1, "s")
```

That in the first case append 1 to an initially empty list is faster than putting 1 by index in an already created array:

```
Adding into list took: 12.784213542938232 s
Adding into array took: 19.65919280052185 s
```

Why? I thought that resizing the list would create a small overhead?
I've tried it on linux and windows. I obtain the same results.

Comment: `numpy` is faster if you stay in `numpy`.  You're doing 100 million transitions from Python to C and back to Python here, and those transitions have overhead.  numpy wins when you can vectorize, like using `np.arange`.

Comment: List append is designed to be fast.  It has a bit of a growth space, so doesn't require frequent rewrite.  Accessing individual items of an array, whether for fetching a value, and setting one, is slower than doing the same thing in a list.  It's the compiled, whole-array, methods of `numpy` that relatively fast.  As a general rule you shouldn't imitate list code with arrays.